# launching batch command using system in python

Tags: batch, python, cmd.exe, gnuwin32

I am trying to use the below command in windows CMD it works.

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\find.exe content_dir/ -type f -not -path 'content_dir/invalid_file/*' -print0
```

Same if i use in python script it does not work, and getting the error as

> `ValueError: invalid \x escape`

```
import os
cmd = "c:\cygwin64\bin\find.exe content_dir/ -type f -not -path 'content_dir/invalid_file/*' -print0"
os.system(cmd)
```

How can i use it in python successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a Raw string:

```
import os
cmd = r'c:\cygwin64\bin\find.exe content_dir/ -type f -not -path "content_dir/invalid_file/*" -print0'
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response and Thanks Wasif, that worked, but just one question if i want to list the files always in the same order(as per the ascii value of name of the files) do i need to add any flags/filters?

Comment: @sravs you can then run `dir` in cmd or `get-childitem` with `sort` in powershell

Comment: I am new for python and power shell, mostly worked in linux, if possible can you post a small example and this has to be done from python script. I will anyway search and find out some examples

Comment: Hey @sravs I am though newbie in linux command line (experienced in Windows and know python), perhaps you could see `man find` pages for more idea, or ask a seperate question here?

Comment: Thats fine @Wasif, i will try that :)